# What's wrong with my switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a switch statement in java but I get this error even though my syntax is correct: `Syntax error on token "{", SwitchLabels expected after this token`I know that I can use statements but my teacher told me to use switch as it's prettier to look at, so I've to use switch. I've tried to move the `input=scan.next()` but that gives me another errors

```
switch (true) {
    input = scan.next();
    case 1:
        input.equals("T");
        outToServer.writeBytes("T\r\n");
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;

    case 2:
        input.equals("S");
        outToServer.writeBytes("S\r\n");
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;

    case 3:
        input.equals("Z");
        outToServer.writeBytes("Z\r\n");
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;

    case 4:
        input.equals("D");
        System.out.println("Write a message");
        text = scan.next();
        outToServer.writeBytes("D " + text + "\r\n");
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;

    case 5:
        input.equals("DW");
        outToServer.writeBytes("DW\r\n");
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;

    case 6:
        input.equals("RM20");
        text = "RM20 4" + "\"" + text1 + "\" \"" + text2 + "\" \"" + text3 + "\"" + "\r\n";
        outToServer.writeBytes(text);
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;

    case 7:
        input.equals("Q");
        clientSocket.close();
        System.out.println("The server is disconnected");
        break;
}
```

Comment: what's right with your switch statement? `switch(true)`is wrong, `input = scan.next();`doesn't belong in the switch statement.... RTFM

Answer (score 9):

Two immediate problems with the first two lines:

```
switch(true){
```

You can't switch on `boolean` values

```
input = scan.next();
```

You've got this line immediately within the `switch` statement - it needs to be within a `case` statement.

I suspect you want:

```
String input = scan.next();
switch (input) {
    case "T":
        ...
        break;
    case "S":
        ...
        break;
    // Other cases
    default:
        ...
        break;
}
```

Or get rid of the `input` variable if you don't need it for anything else:

```
switch (scan.next()) {
```

(I'd also strongly advise you to revisit your indentation. While `switch/case` statements can be indented in a number of ways, your current approach is really hard to read, IMO.)

Given things like this in your original code:

```
case 7: input.equals("Q");
```

... it seems to me that you probably don't understand what a switch statement actually does. Stack Overflow isn't a good place to learn the basics of a language like that - I suggest you read the [Java tutorial on `switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), or a good book, or ask your teacher for more help.

Comment: if you use input in switch, then you would need to quote case values i.e. `case "1"`.

Comment: Ok can I change true to a string?

Comment: @SMA: Well, depending on what `scan.next()` returns. If `scan` is a `Scanner`, then yes. Edited with that assumption.

Comment: @Hodhod: You can, but you'd still want it to be some useful variable. It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve, or whether you've understood what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I think your edit sort of lowered the value of the answer... The user is trying to match the strings "S", "Z" etc. for his cases, the numbers actually don't make sense.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Ah, I hadn't actually looked at the code within the cases. Basically it makes no sense at all at the moment... Have now edited.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order from:

```
switch(true){
input = scan.next();
```

To

```
input = scan.next();
inputNumber = scan.nextInt();
switch(inputNumber){//or from java 7 use input directly but quote your case values.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch(true){
`input = scan.next()`;// This is error line.
```

After switch statement case is required. and You are accepting value from user.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a switch statement with a boolean argument.
`switch(true)` is not a valid statement.

String switch are not allowed in Java 6 but are allowed in Java 7 and Java 8.

Also equals method return a boolean and you are not saving this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your syntax is nowhere near correct.

You want to input the value first. Since Java 7, you can switch on a string.

So:

- Input first.
- Declare what you want to switch on. In this case, it's your `input` variable.
- Then declare the cases. The declarations are not `case i: input.equals("what you want")`. They are simply `case "what you want"`.

So, the equivalent of `if` statements such as

```
input = scan.next();
if ( input.equals("T") ) {
    outToServer.writeBytes("T\r\n");
    System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
} else if ( input.equals("S") ) {
    outToServer.writeBytes("S\r\n");
    System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
}
...
```

Is actually:

```
input = scan.next();
switch ( input ) {
    case "T" :
        outToServer.writeBytes("T\r\n");
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;

    case "S" :
        outToServer.writeBytes("S\r\n");
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;
    ...
}
```

And in fact, you can join together all the cases that do the same in a single case:

```
input = scan.next();
switch ( input ) {
    case "T" :
    case "S" :
    ... // More case labels that should be treated the same

        outToServer.writeBytes(input + "\r\n");
        System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
        break;

    ... // Other, non-similar cases
}
```

Comment: Note that the code after "T", "S", "Z", "DW" is practically identical and could be coded with a single branch, using `input + "\r\n"` in lieu of the literal T/S/Z/DW in the writeBytes method call.

Comment: @laune Right. Added that to my answer.